# Plot a Numpy array with shape (200, 200) shows a vertical line instead of a square

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, itk

I've just started to learn Python 3.7.7.

I'm trying to show a NIFTI images, as numpy array with float32 elements, using plot.

This is the code to show the images:

```
import os
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

def plot_grey_images_as_figure(img1, img2, title1, title2):
    """
    Show img1 and img2 as a single figure using matplotlib.pylot.

    Show img1 and img2 as a single figure using matplotlib.pylot with the titles
    title1 for img1 and title2 for img2.

    Parameters:
    img1 (array-like or PIL image): Image to show first.
    img2 (array-like or PIL image): Image to show second.
    title1 (string) : Title for image 1.
    title2 (string) : Title for image 2.

    Returns:
    Nothing.

    """    

    plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img1, cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title(title1), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(img2, cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title(title2), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    plt.show()

    return
```

This is how I preprocess the image before displaying them:

```
def preprocessing_array(array, rows_standard, cols_standard, debug): # array shape is (48, 240, 240)

    image_rows_Dataset = np.shape(array)[1]   
    image_cols_Dataset = np.shape(array)[2]

    num_rows_1 = ((image_rows_Dataset // 2) - (rows_standard // 2)) #  20
    num_rows_2 = ((image_rows_Dataset // 2) + (rows_standard // 2)) # 220
    num_cols_1 = ((image_cols_Dataset // 2) - (cols_standard // 2)) #  20
    num_cols_2 = ((image_cols_Dataset // 2) + (cols_standard // 2)) # 220

    array = array[:, num_rows_1:num_rows_2, num_cols_1:num_cols_2]


    ### ------ New Axis --------------------------------------------------------
    # Add a new axis to denote that this is a one channel image.
    array  = array[..., np.newaxis] 

    return array  # array shape is (48, 200, 200, 1)
```

To display the images I do this:

```
# D is a dataset with shape (960, 2, 200, 200, 1) with float32 elements.
print("Shape: ", D[:,0,:][0].shape)
nifti.plot_grey_images_as_figure(D[:,0,:][0][:,-1], D[:,1,:][0][:,-1], "mask", "output")
```

And I get this output:

[image]

Why am I getting lines instead of squares?

Maybe the problem is that I add a new axis, and then I remove it because doesn't allow me to plot an image with shape `(200, 200, 1)`.

Comment: What is the shape of images you send to plot function?

Comment: @Vishnudev What a mistake!!! D[:,0,:][0][:,-1].shape is (200, 1). I think I need to learn more about Numpy arrays.

Comment: It should be `D[:,0,:][0][:, :, 0]` which gives a shape of `(200, 200)`.

Comment: Now it makes sense (after the update): `D.shape = (960, 2, 200, 200, 1)`

Comment: @CypherX Sorry, I do a lot of things wrong.

Comment: What do you use the axis (`axis=0`) with `dimension=960` for? do you make a plot for each index along `axis=0`?

Comment: @CypherX There are 960 pairs of images of 200 width, 200 height, 1 channel. I use them to train a CNN. The first image in the pair is the X_train (features), and the second one is the Y_train (label).

Comment: Got it. Take a look at my updated solution: you can directly use the variable `D` to extract `mask` and `output` images for each pair.

Comment: Qustion: shouldn't the shape of the output of `preprocessing_array()` be `(480, 240, 240)`?

Comment: @CypherX No, each patience has 48 slices (images), so there are 20 patients. The `(48, 200, 200, 1)` are the brain images, and there are another `(48, 200, 200, 1)` masks. These are the pair images.

Comment: I see. Thank you. What if you reshape the data as `(20, 48, 2, 200, 200, 1)`? This will allow you to feed your data along the first axis (dim for patients). Use `D.reshape((20, 48, 2, 200, 200, 1))`, if you would like to adopt this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.sqeeze()` to drop the size-one dimension. The problem was in passing the images as non-2D arrays. *Squeezing* helps us in dropping the dimension along `axis=2`, making the shape from `(200, 200, 1)` *to* `(200, 200)`.

```py
import numpy as np
np.queeze(D[:,0,:][0], axis=2).shape
# (200, 200)
```

### Suggested Improvement

```py
# Choose the index i (axis=0)
i = 0 # Values (0, 1, ..., 960)

# Extract mask and output images
img1 = D[i,0,:,:,0] # shape (200, 200) --> mask
img2 = D[i,1,:,:,0] # shape (200, 200) --> output
nifti.plot_grey_images_as_figure(img1, img2, "mask", "output")
```

### Reference

1. [`numpy.squeeze()` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

Comment: @VansFannel I think your code could be shortened and streamlined in a few places. Suggested something in the solution. Please take a look at it and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The image slicing is not correct. Your plot function should be

```
base = D[:,0,:]
img1 = base[0][:, :, 0] # Shape of (200, 200)
img2 = base[1][:, :, 0]
nifti.plot_grey_images_as_figure(img1, img2, "mask", "output")
```